# iPhone modify image of CMSampleBuffer

Tags: iphone, image, video, edit

I am writing an iPhone application that capture video from iPhone back camera and edit that video and record edited video. The following are the functions to perform.

1. Get video from back camera.
2. Record the video to some location in iPhone.
3. Get the 1 mins duration video from the recorded video.
4. Get the frame by frame CMSampleBuffer from the video.
5. Modify the image of the CMSampleBuffer and write the modified video in the iPhone.

The steps 1 – 4 are worked fine for me. But the modification of image of the CMSampleBuffer are not working. The modifications I want to perform is draw an additional image in the image of CMSampleBuffer. Draw some texts in the image of the CMSampleBuffer. Can somebody tell me how can I do this?